# Time-locked deposit protocol?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, smart-lock

I am designing a protocol where a user **A** sends a **time-locked deposit** to user that if the user B within time **t** provide a proof that he exists in a location **x** (this may be obtained by third party like Google), user B can get the deposit of **A**. Otherwise, **A** can get his money back.
Any help of how to do that using cryptography or two-way secure computations?

Answer (score 1):

As this is an Ethereum forum, I assume you are interested in creating a contract which implements such functionality.

What you need is a contract which:

1) Accepts Ethers from user **A**

2) Upon receiving proofs of **x** from an oracle (oracle can get the data from for example Google) checks the timestamp. If current time is greater than **t** the contract forwards the stored Ethers to user **B**. Otherwise it probably does nothing.

3) According to some rules if user **B** can't provide requires proofs the contract sends the Ethers back to **A**.

This is a basic approach. To make it a bit more secure, consider applying the *withdrawal pattern* (https://medium.com/@jgm.orinoco/why-use-the-withdrawal-pattern-d5255921ca2a) instead of sending Ethers.